# Getting MethodNotAllowedHttpException, can't see where I screwed up. Need a second set of eyes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Okay, I'll start by saying I'm blind. I did something in my routes that caused a MethodNotAllowedHttpException to throw up but can't see the issue. I need a second set of eyes to see what the issue here is. It's right in front of me but I can't make the connection..

Routes:

```
Route::get('cms', 'CmsController@index');

Route::get('login', 'CmsController@index');
Route::get('cms/login', 'CmsController@login');
Route::get('cms/dashboard', 'CmsController@index');
```

Controller:

```
class CmsController extends BaseController {

public function index()
{
    return View::make('cms.login');
}

public function login()
{
    if (Auth::attempt(array('username' => Input::get('username'), 'password' => Input::get('password'))))
    {
        return Redirect::intended('cms/dashboard');
    }   
    else
    {
        return Redirect::to('/login');
    }   
}
```

Comment: Which route is throwing that error and how is the route accessed? I suspect your login form is set as `method="POST"` but your routes are all "GET"

Comment: I use /login and enter credentials, redirects to cms/login and throws up the error.

Comment: can you paste the error stack..

Comment: Is your login `<form method="POST"` or not?

Answer (score 0):

Accidentally pulled old form from git, removed form method = "POST"